# Lines where datetime is between 2 datetime values SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I want to only have the sql values where the value of the datetime is between 2 values.

I use this code

```
 filterdatum = "(Datum >= "+ startwaarde + " AND Datum < "+ eindwaarde+ ")";
 filter = filter + " AND " + filterdatum;
```

My filter will look like this:

```
where "(Type like '%13%') AND (Datum >= 11/04/2013 00:00:00 AND Datum < 23/04/2013 00:00:00)"
```

I always get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '00'.

Comment: place the dates between single quotes

Comment: This is open to SQL injection. Use parameters

Comment: @noobob, this comment should arguably be an answer as opposed to a comment as you are entirely correct ;)

Comment: @Moo-Juice ok. I did it

Comment: @user2282583, it is customary on SO to mark the correct answer as correct :)  See the tick marks below.

Comment: Best way to thank me is to mark my answer correct :) as @Moo-Juice explained

Answer (score 4):

Place the dates between single quotes:

```
filterdatum = "(Datum >= '"+ startwaarde + "' AND Datum < '"+ eindwaarde+ "')";
 filter = filter + " AND " + filterdatum;
```

**Hint**: A simple test you can do next time is to execute your query directly in your database and check if it works.

Answer (score 3):

The better option is to pass the date values as parameters to the query. Putting date values as strings directly in the query string is always problematic. The exact code to create and pass parameters depends on your data access technology.

If you are using ADO.NET, you should write:

```
filterdatum = "(Datum >= @startDate AND Datum < @endDate)";
...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startwaarde);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", eindwaarde);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you quote the DateTimes, otherwise your SQL might think they're table/column names?

Comment: How must i place my quotes then?

Answer (score 2):

You should use single quotes between your date values.

```
filterdatum = "(Datum >= '"+ startwaarde + "' AND Datum < '"+ eindwaarde+ "')";
```

But more important, you should always use *[parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)*, this kind of codes are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attacks.

For example;

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
conn.Open();
string s = "SELECT * From YourTable WHERE Datum >= @startwaarde AND Datum < @eindwaarde";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startwaarde", startwaarde);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@eindwaarde", eindwaarde);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Just to mention he didn't specified if this is an ADO command or a grid filter or something similar. Right?

Comment: @noobob Yeah of course.. But doesn't matter which tech he used, he should always parameterize his queries..

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your date/time values between quotes.
2. Make sure your date/time values are formatted conform [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You can do this with `startwaarde.ToString("o")`, assuming `startwaarde` is of type DateTime.
3. The best way is to use parameters. So your SQL will look like: `(Datum >= @1 AND Datum < @2)` and you add the two values as parameters to the `SqlCommand`, assuming your are filtering on a database.